# Inserting a value into all possible locations in a list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to do print all the possible outcomes of a given list and I was wondering how to put a value into various locations in the list. For example, if my list was `[A, B]`, I want to insert `X` into all possible index of the list such that it would return this `[X, A, B]`, `[A, X, B]`, `[A, B, X]`.

I was thinking about using `range(len())` and a for loop but not sure how to start.

Comment: "all possible outcomes of a given list" of length 3 would give you 6 permutations.

Comment: I know, I just didn't write them all out

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could do this with the following list comprehension:

```
[mylist[i:] + [newelement] + mylist[:i] for i in xrange(len(mylist),-1,-1)]
```

With your example:

```
>>> mylist=['A','B']
>>> newelement='X'
>>> [mylist[i:] + [newelement] + mylist[:i] for i in xrange(len(mylist),-1,-1)]
[['X', 'A', 'B'], ['B', 'X', 'A'], ['A', 'B', 'X']]
```

Comment: is there a difference between xrange and range? and is it possible to do:
    for i in xrange(len(mylist),-1,-1):
        mylist[i:] + [newelement] + mylist[:i]

because this is for homework and I never learned the way how you wrote it

Comment: range generates each number in the sequence all at once and returns these numbers in a list.

xrange generates each number in the range *as you need it*.  Thus xrange uses less memory (a lot less if the sequence is quite large).  So unless you really need all the numbers at once, xrange can be more efficient.

The code you suggest would also do the trick.  (Though you might want to do something with the lists you construct in the body of the for loop).

Comment: Option for modern Python that involves fewer temporaries is to replace `mylist[i:] + [newelement] + mylist[:i]` with `[*mylist[i:], newelement, *mylist[:i]]`. Won't make a major difference in performance, but the additional unpacking generalizations added in 3.5 are awesome, use 'em. :-)

Answer (score 95):

Use [insert()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html) to insert an element before a given position.

For instance, with

```
arr = ['A','B','C']
arr.insert(0,'D')
```

arr becomes `['D','A','B','C']` because `D` is inserted before the element at index 0.

Now, for

```
arr = ['A','B','C']
arr.insert(4,'D')
```

arr becomes `['A','B','C','D']` because `D` is inserted before the element at index 4 (which is 1 beyond the end of the array).

However, if you are looking to generate all permutations of an array, there are ways to do this already built into Python. The itertools package has a permutation generator.

Here's some example code:

```
import itertools
arr = ['A','B','C']
perms = itertools.permutations(arr)
for perm in perms:
    print perm
```

will print out

```
('A', 'B', 'C')
('A', 'C', 'B')
('B', 'A', 'C')
('B', 'C', 'A')
('C', 'A', 'B')
('C', 'B', 'A')
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to insert a list into a list, you can do this:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> for x in reversed(['a','b','c']): a.insert(2,x)
>>> a
[1, 2, 'a', 'b', 'c', 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest is use list[i:i]

```
    a = [1,2, 3, 4]
    a[2:2] = [10]
```

Print a to check insertion

```
    print a
    [1, 2, 10, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, you just give one approach on how to insert at a given position in a list. Question asked for result in the form of all resulting lists when inserting a value in all possible positions.

Comment: In Python 3.7 and above `name = ["John, "James", "Tim"]

name[1:1] = "Sam"

print(name)

['John', 'S', 'a', 'm', 'James', 'Tim']`

Which is not the element insertion expected.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from JavaScript, this was something I was used to having "built-in" via [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), so I made a Python function that does the same:

```
def list_splice(target, start, delete_count=None, *items):
    """Remove existing elements and/or add new elements to a list.

    target        the target list (will be changed)
    start         index of starting position
    delete_count  number of items to remove (default: len(target) - start)
    *items        items to insert at start index

    Returns a new list of removed items (or an empty list)
    """
    if delete_count == None:
        delete_count = len(target) - start

    # store removed range in a separate list and replace with *items
    total = start + delete_count
    removed = target[start:total]
    target[start:total] = items

    return removed
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, a solution that:

1. Allows inserting multiple values into all possible locations, not just one, and
2. Minimizes temporaries
3. Does not invoke `O(n * m)` work on the insertions (which naïve repeated calls to `list.insert` would perform)

Bonus, (for the person who asked [a duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66921858/364696)) it makes use of [the `itertools` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) without it feeling completely forced:

```python
import itertools

l1 = ['a','b','c','d','f']
l2 = ['Z', 'Y']

combined_indices = range(len(l1)+len(l2))
iterators = itertools.cycle(l1), itertools.cycle(l2)

l3 = []
for positions in map(frozenset, itertools.combinations(combined_indices , len(l2))):
    l3.append([next(iterators[idx in positions]) for idx in combined_indices])

print(*l3, sep="\n")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7RasMwDEXf/RWiL7Y3U2jyNuiHdFkYrqNsAkc2th/a/Xxmhy2wVXARlq58T7yXz8D9utISQypABVMJwWch/AnOMEgrjbxWuaqpapaj8N22epUG5KW@hQvLlRind@KJHOa6TpY/UHlk5U/6eeud1qIF2BJSs@xhR3d3HpvRPA47XVn6FjiKOSSIIVOhwBmIYbFRzSl8IWcsf443IrsZ1QOegV8g/SKglu@PNkbkSQ2Mt6J2zIGmWwvaU0cNjeJn/P/nscLGRFzUk@8NZIznwxsf9Lp@Aw)

which produces output of the form:

```python
['Z', 'Y', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f']
['Z', 'a', 'Y', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f']
['Z', 'a', 'b', 'Y', 'c', 'd', 'f']
['Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'Y', 'd', 'f']
['Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'Y', 'f']
['Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'Y']
['a', 'Z', 'Y', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f']
['a', 'Z', 'b', 'Y', 'c', 'd', 'f']
# ... eleven lines omitted ...
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'Z', 'f', 'Y']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'Z', 'Y']
```

And for bonus fun, a version that inserts the elements of `l2` in either order (and condenses the work to an absurdly complicated listcomp for funsies):

```python
from itertools import cycle, permutations, repeat

l1 = ['a','b','c','d','f']
l2 = ['Z', 'Y']

combined_indices = range(len(l1)+len(l2))
i1next = cycle(l1).__next__

l3 = [[pos_to_l2[pos] if pos in pos_to_l2 else i1next() for pos in combined_indices]
      for pos_to_l2 in map(dict, map(zip, permutations(combined_indices, len(l2)), repeat(l2)))]

print(*l3, sep="\n")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDRbsMgDHznK6y@ABualOS5H7J2EUoTZ0MigMCV2v185rBm0op0ss0dZ@x0p68YunWdc1zAEWaK0RdwS4qZYLyPHg0kzMuVBnIxFAMZEw4khG/gCGc5SCMvjJExMWbZC99W6iQNyHeuxRiXiws4WRcmN2JhOg/hE5XHoHyjX2tstRauCXgj5mvvjXuzdruyllt2m@85xWIpWt9uWQ9uBo7gAvwRgL4g/HopDXPMu@T5J72Aeh6Sx3MWLkNSrCBTs2@X/u9BPRsZ2GfYV1QLzdOn7AKpF98ZKJiOh49w0Ov6Aw)

which behaves the same, but produces outputs where the elements of `l2` are inserted in either order (when `l2[0]` shifts right, the other elements of `l2` are inserted before it before they continue inserting after it, as in the first solution, e.g. the output sequence:

```python
...
['Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'Y']
['a', 'Z', 'Y', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f']
...
```

expands to:

```python
...
['Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'Y']
['Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f']  # New
['a', 'Z', 'Y', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f']
...
```

Answer (score -1):

If `l` is your list and `X` is your value:

```
for i in range(len(l) + 1):
    print l[:i] + [X] + l[i:]
```

Comment: the remove call might remove another instance of X