# Running median of y-values over a range of x

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, median, scatter

Below is a scatter plot I constructed from two numpy arrays.

Scatter Plot Example
[image]

What I'd like to add to this plot is a running median of y over a range of x. I've photoshoped in an example:

Modified Scatter Plot
[image]

Specifically, I need the median for data points in bins of 1 unit along the x axis between two values (this range will vary between many plots, but I can manually adjust it). I appreciate any tips that can point me in the right direction.

Comment: are there any dependencies or correlation between the sets of y-values in adjacent bins? unless there are, you'll have to apply a standard median computation on each set.

Comment: No, each bin can be treated as separate. To calculate the overall median in the plot, I used pylab.median on all y values. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how I can break up the values into specific sized bins over a range of x. Once I've got past that hurdle, I can repeat the median calculation on each bin.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would use [`np.digitize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) to do the bin sorting for you. This way you can easily apply any function and set the range you are interested in.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

N = 2000
total_bins = 10

# Sample data
X = np.random.random(size=N)*10
Y = X**2 + np.random.random(size=N)*X*10

bins = np.linspace(X.min(),X.max(), total_bins)
delta = bins[1]-bins[0]
idx  = np.digitize(X,bins)
running_median = [np.median(Y[idx==k]) for k in range(total_bins)]

plt.scatter(X,Y,color='k',alpha=.2,s=2)
plt.plot(bins-delta/2,running_median,'r--',lw=4,alpha=.8)
plt.axis('tight')
plt.show()
```

[image]

As an example of the versatility of the method, let's add errorbars given by the standard deviation of each bin:

```
running_std    = [Y[idx==k].std() for k in range(total_bins)]
plt.errorbar(bins-delta/2,running_median,
              running_std,fmt=None)
```

[image]

Comment: That's great. Thanks for providing a little extra as well!

Answer (score 5):

This problem can also be efficiently tackled via [python pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) (Python Data Analysis Library), which offers native data cutting and analysis methods.

Consider this

(Kudos and +1 to @Hooked for his example from which I borrowed the `X` and `Y` data)

```
 import pandas as pd
 df = pd.DataFrame({'X' : X, 'Y' : Y})  #we build a dataframe from the data

 data_cut = pd.cut(df.X,bins)           #we cut the data following the bins
 grp = df.groupby(by = data_cut)        #we group the data by the cut

 ret = grp.aggregate(np.median)         #we produce an aggregate representation (median) of each bin

 #plotting

 plt.scatter(df.X,df.Y,color='k',alpha=.2,s=2)
 plt.plot(ret.X,ret.Y,'r--',lw=4,alpha=.8)
 plt.show()
```

Remark: here the x values of the red curve are the bin-wise x-medians (the midpoints of the bins can be used).

[image]

Comment: Great approach. I tried all of the suggestions and each worked very well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can create a function based on `numpy.median()` that will calculate the median value given the intervals:

```
import numpy as np

def medians(x, y, intervals):
    out = []
    for xmin, xmax in intervals:
        mask = (x >= xmin) & (x < xmax)
        out.append(np.median(y[mask]))
    return np.array(out)
```

Then use this function for the desired intervals:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

intervals = ((18, 19), (19, 20), (20, 21), (21, 22))
centers = [(xmin+xmax)/2. for xmin, xmax in intervals]

plt.plot(centers, medians(x, y, intervals)
```

Comment: Great approach. I tried all of the suggestions and each worked very well. Thanks!

Comment: If intervals are consecutive, you could use the itertools pairwise recipe: `intervals = pairwise((18, 19, 20, 21, 22))` or `pairwise(range(18, 23, 1))`

Answer (score 1):

I've written something like this in `C#`. I don't do Python so here is the pseudocode:

- create a `List` to use for the data which the median will be derived from
- sort scatter plot points by `x` value
- cycle through the sorted points by `x` value
- for each point insert the `Y` value of that point into the median list  so that the median list grows as a sorted list. i.e. insert Y so the List value above and below it are > and < it respectively. Take a look here: [Inserting values into specific locations in a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218238/inserting-values-into-specific-locations-in-a-list-in-python) .
- after each `Y` value is added, the median value will be the list value at the current middle index i.e. `List(List.Length/2)`

Hope it helps!