# How to randomly replace a string in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have something like this:

```
L = ['-','-','-','-','-','-','-']
```

And let's say that I want to replace certain number of those strings. How do I randomly select a position within the list to replace it for something else? For example:

```
L = ['-','*','-','-','-','*','*']
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Maybe start with `import random`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use random.randrange

```
import random

some_list=["-","-","-","-","-","-","-"]

n=2
for i in range(n):
    some_list[random.randrange(0,len(some_list))]="*"
```

Non-repeat solution:

```
import random

some_list=["-","-","-","-","-","-","-"]

n=8
if n>len(some_list):
    some_list=["*" for i in some_list]
else:
    for i in range(n):
           position=random.randrange(0,len(some_list))
           while some_list[position]=="*":
                   position=random.randrange(0,len(some_list))
           some_list[position]="*"

print(some_list)
```

Comment: What if `random.randrange(0, len(some_list)) returns the same value in the two calls?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can use the module `random` and its function `randint`, as it follows:

```
import random

num_replacements = 3 
L = ['-','-','-','-','-','-','-']

idx = random.sample(range(len(L)), num_replacements)

for i in idx:
    L[i] = '*'
```

For more information, you can check the `random` module documentation at: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

EDIT: Now sampling random number using `random.sample`, rather than using `random.randint`, which may generate the same number during different iterations.

Comment: Separate calls to randint can generate the same number. It might be better to use `random.sample`.

Answer (score 2):

```
import random as r

L = ['-','-','-','-','-','-','-']

def replaceit(L,char):
    L[r.randint(0,len(L))] = char
    return L

newL = replaceit(L,'*')
print newL
```

Simply call replaceit with newL to replace another random character.

Answer (score 1):

use `random.choice`

```
import random

L = ['-','-','-','-','-','-','-']

while L.count('*') < 3:
    pos = random.choice(range(len(L)))
    L[pos] = '*'

print(L)
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose u want to replace it with 'a' :

try the following:

```
from random import *

L = ['-','-','-','-','-','-','-']
r = randint(0,len(L))
L[r] = 'a'

print L
```

Answer (score 0):

i have a Java background, a newbie to python.
I will suggest to generate a random number from first to last index of that list, and insert the new string to the newly generated index.

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218238/inserting-values-into-specific-locations-in-a-list-in-python) to insert a value at a specific position in a list.

Answer (score 0):

This non-repeat solution relies on [`random.shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html?highlight=random.shuffle#random.shuffle):

```
>>> import random
>>> L = ['-','-','-','-','-','-','-']
>>> n = 3    # number of strings to replace
>>> indices = range(len(L))
>>> random.shuffle(indices)
>>> for i in indices[:n]:
...     L[i] = '*'
... 
>>> L
['-', '*', '*', '-', '*', '-', '-']
```