# Recursively replacing items in a list with items of a different list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've implemented the exact same functionality with recursions, I also want a version without recursion as Python has a recursion limit and there are problems while sharing data.

```
sublist2 = [{'nothing': "Notice This"}]
sublist1 = [{'include':[sublist2]}]

mainlist = [{'nothing': 1}, {'include':[sublist1, sublist2]},
            {'nothing': 2}, {'include':[sublist2]}]
```

What is to be filled in the Todo?

```
for i in mainlist:
    if 'nothing' in i:
         # Do nothing
    else if 'include' in i:
         # Todo
         # Append the contents of the list mentioned recursively
         # in it's own place without disrupting the flow
```

After the operation the expected result

```
mainlist = [{'nothing': 1}, 
            {'nothing': "Notice This"}, {'nothing': "Notice This"}, 
            {'nothing':2}, 
            {'nothing': "Notice This"}]
```

If you notice sublist1 references to sublist2. That's the reason

{'include':[sublist1, sublist2]} is replaced by

{'nothing':"Notice This"}, {'nothing':"Notice This"}

I've tried the following

[Inserting values into specific locations in a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218238/inserting-values-into-specific-locations-in-a-list-in-python)

[How to get item's position in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364621/howt-to-get-items-position-in-a-list)

Comment: I am confused. Do you want to do this recursively or not? Your first paragraph and title contradict eachother.

Comment: You're correct that Python has recursion limits (defaulting to 1000), but if your data structure is breaking that, then I'd say there's something seriously wrong with your data.

Comment: @Jokab I meant the list should populate recursively. I don't want to use recursions. Will correct it

Comment: @JonClements There are problems with data sharing and speed. I've replicated it to a smaller scale to explain it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using recursion, you just look at the nth element and change it in place until it doesn't need any further processing.

```
sublist2 = [{'nothing': "Notice This"}]
sublist1 = [{'include':[sublist2]}]

mainlist = [{'nothing': 1}, {'include':[sublist1, sublist2]},
            {'nothing': 2}, {'include':[sublist2]}]

index = 0
while index < len(mainlist):
    if 'nothing' in mainlist[index]:
        index += 1
    elif 'include' in mainlist[index]:
        # replace the 'include' entries with their corresponding list
        mainlist[index:index+1] = mainlist[index]['include']
    elif isinstance(mainlist[index], list):
        # if an entry is a list, replace it with its entries
        mainlist[index:index+1] = mainlist[index]
```

Note the difference between assigning to an entry `l[0]` and assigning to a slice `l[0:1]`

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> l[3] = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, ['a', 'b', 'c']]
>>> l[0:1] = ['x', 'y', 'z']
>>> l
>>> ['x', 'y', 'z', 2, 3, ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```