# Put a variable in a specific array position Python

Tags: python, arrays, function

I am trying to solve a problem and I am not able to do it. So the problem is that I have a function in Python. And I have 3 cases and I want my function to be general for all these cases. So my function needs an argument which is a array like this `a = [a1, a2, a3]` and for each case 2 of the elements in the array are constant and the other is variable, I explain this in more detail with this example code:

```
# I have my function:

def example(r,a):
    # r is an array. Inside this function I have a for loop
    for i in xrange(len(r)):
         #inside this loop is where I have the 3 cases:
         a = [r[z], a[1], a[2]]
         a = [a[0], r[z], a[2]]    
         a = [a[0], a[1], r[z]]
    (rest of the code)
     ...
```

so I want to find a way to declare `a` so my function knows where to place the variable `r[z]` I know that it is posible to do it with if statments but I am looking for a one-line solution, something like a way to put the variable r[z] in a given position of the array a. Or I don't know any efficient way is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Regards

Comment: Use `.insert()` or `a[:i] + [item] + a[i:] `

Answer (score 0):

Use `insert()` to insert an element before a given position.

For instance, with

```
arr = ['A','B','C']
arr.insert(0,'D')
arr becomes ['D','A','B','C']
```

because 'D' is inserted before the element at index 0.

Now, for

```
arr = ['A','B','C']
arr.insert(4,'D')
arr becomes ['A','B','C','D']
```

because 'D' is inserted before the element at index 4 (which is 1 beyond the end of the array).

Original answer: [Inserting values into specific locations in a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218238/inserting-values-into-specific-locations-in-a-list-in-python)

Comment: Mmm yes but this doesn't solve my problem, since how can I define the array so the function instert my variable in a given position. I mean I want to provide the function the information of where to insert the variable inside of the array. Something like:

a=['inserthere',a2,a3]

so the function will insert the variable in the place of 'inserthere'

Comment: You pass that position to insert(), so I don't get your point

Answer (score 0):

I have found I way of doing it:

```
 #if I define a as:

 a = [a1, True, a3]

 # I can use

 np.place(a, a==True, r[z])
```

In this way it will replace the value where a[i] = true by r[z]