# Python string to list per character

Tags: python, string, list

Good day I just want to understand the logic behind this code

```
lst = []
word = "ABCD"
lst[:0] = word

print(lst)
```

OUTPUT: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] why not ['ABCD'] how?

```
for i in word: # this code I understand it's looping through the string
  lst.append(i) # then appending to list
```

but the first code above I don't get the logic.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39541370/how-to-insert-multiple-elements-into-a-list

Comment: You're assigning to a slice, so it treats `word` as an iterable.  To get what you want, you need `lst[:0] = [word]`.  This will insert `word` to the front of `lst`.  If you instead want to overwrite the entire list (e.g., if it's non-empty), you can do `lst[:] = [word]`.

Comment: I'm not sure what the original rationale was for making a `str` an iterable of `str`s, rather than having a separate non-iterable type `char`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lst[:0] = ...` is implemented by `lst.__setitem__(slice(0, None, 0), ...)`, where `...` is an arbitrary iterable.

The resulting slice is the empty list at the beginning of `lst` (though in this case, it doesn't really matter since `lst` is empty), so each element of `...` is inserted into `lst`, starting at the beginning.

You can see this starting with a non-empty list.

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3]
>>> word = "ABCD"
>>> lst[:0] = word
>>> lst
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 1, 2, 3]
```

To get `lst == ['ABCD']`, you need to make the right-hand side an iterable *containing* the string:

```
lst[:0] = ('ABCD', )  # ['ABCD'] would also work.
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's a well known way to convert string to a list character by character

you can find here -> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-convert-string-list/

if you wanna try to get your list element like 'ABCD' then try

lst[:0] = [word,]

by doing that you specify that you need whole word as an element