# How to add a list to another list in python at a certain index

Tags: python, list

For example, how do i do this:

```
x=[1,2,3]
y=[4,5,6]
list3=[1,4,5,6,2,3]
```

i do not want `[1,[4,5,6],2,3]`

basically i want to extend it, but at a given index

Comment: What code have you written to give you the unwanted result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert multiple elements into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39541370/how-to-insert-multiple-elements-into-a-list)

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips. This is a nice first question, though it'd be even better if you had done your own research first. I found the above question by googling `python insert multiple items into list`.

Comment: i used list.insert(index,list2) to insert the 2nd list at given index, but i need it to be inserted as individual integers, not collectively as a list

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add minimal reproducible example, or at least an attempt. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select an empty slice at the index you want, and insert the other list there:

```py
>>> x=[1,2,3]
>>> y=[4,5,6]
>>> x[1:1]=y
>>> x
[1, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use slice assignment.

```
list3 = x[:] # make copy of x
list3[1:1] = y # replace empty slice at index 1
```