# Replace list value by values in another list

Tags: python

I have a dictionary, where value is a list and I want to create a list from each string (elements are separated by a comma) and then replace the string from the original list by values from the list created from the string.

So I have this code:

```
import numpy as np
nan = np.nan
d1 = {'Cells open': [nan, nan, 'In1, In2, Ga1, As', 'As', 'In1, In2, P', nan, nan, "Si", nan]}
cell_list_1 = []
cells = d1["Cells open"]
for num, cell in enumerate(cells):
    if type(cell) == str:
        cell_list_2 = cell.split(",")
        cell_list_3 = [c.strip() for c in cell_list_2]
        cells[num] = cell_list_3
print(cells)
```

The output is:

```
[nan, nan, ['In1', 'In2', 'Ga1', 'As'], ['As'], ['In1', 'In2', 'P'], nan, nan, nan, nan]
```

But I want the output to be:

```
[nan, nan, 'In1', 'In2', 'Ga1', 'As', 'As', 'In1', 'In2', 'P', nan, nan, nan, nan]
```

So basically I want to unpack the lists so that I only have one dimensional list. How can I do this?

I tried:

```
ls1 = d1["Cells open"]
a = list(map(lambda x: *x if type(x) == list else x, ls1))
print(d1)
```

But I get: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Can somebody help?

**EDIT:**
I checked jonrsharpe's suggestion on [How to insert multiple elements into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39541370/how-to-insert-multiple-elements-into-a-list) but I still can't get my code to work. Could somebody still help?

Comment: You could do `cells = cells[:num] + cell_list_3 + cells[num:]` or maybe `cells[num:num] = cell_list_3`. In your conditional block.

Comment: Hi Blyfh, I tried both of those codes and neither of them worked.

Comment: Sorry, should've tested it beforehand. The second approach actually creates an infinite loop.  (the slice should look like this: `num:num+1`) But the first works perfectly fine. I just took your code and replaced line 10 with `cells = cells[:num] + cell_list_3 + cells[num:]`. What exactly doesn't work on your side?